# Memory leaks with custom QAbstractTableModel and custom QTableView in PyQt5 5.5.1

Tags: python-3.x, memory-leaks, pyqt5

I have a rather big project, written in Python 3.4 and PyQt5 5.5.1.
After updating to PyQt5 version 5.5.1 from PyQt5 version 5.4.1 I have strange memory leaks, there are no any leaks on 5.4.1 version.
I have custom QAbstractTableModel and custom QTableView in my project with delegates for data types, also I have overridden timerEvent method in both these clases. Timer event of QAbstractTableModel refreshes table data using layotAboutToBeChanged and layoutChanged signals, when I remove this method I decrease memory leaks. But I also have memory leaks when I open editor in table view and close it.

What can be a reason for this strange behaviour? There were no any leaks with older version of PyQt5.

Comment: There is no point asking a question like this unless you can provide a simple test case so that others can try to reproduce the problem. Nobody can debug/analyse code that they cannot see.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with simple example, example will be rather large, I don't think that anybody will read my example, I will post it later. But my question was, why I have memory leak in new PyQt5 version and have no in old version with the same code. May be there are "critical" changes in PyQt? There were no memory leaks in PyQt4 too.

Comment: Exactly how did you detect this memory leak? Surely it must give you a strong hint as to where the issue lies.

Comment: After updating PyQt on Windows I had random app crashes and I saw a lot of using RAM in task manager. After downgrade of PyQt memory usage decreased. And now I have leaks on Linux after PyQt update.